# How do I filter a php 2d-array to return elements with a name attribute that contains the search query as a wildcard ?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, search

My two-dimmensional array looks like :

```
        $users = [ 
                   [name: "John Doe", email: 'e@e.com'], 
                   [name: 'Patrice', email: 'pt@ex.com']
                 ];
```

I am trying to write a function that returns an array of only elements containing the query in the name attribute

For example:

```
         //if $q= 'e', the function will return the original array as both array elements have the substring 'e' in the value of the name attribute.
         //if an empty string or no parameter for the query search , return the unadulterated original array.
```

Basically I am trying to have a function that is similar to the following, except it is working with a pre-defined array and not a database;

```
  // Similar Function but with database
 function fetch_data($query)
 {
  $this->db->like('student_name', $query);
  $query = $this->db->get('tbl_student');
  if($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
   foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
   {
    $output[] = array(
     'name'  => $row["student_name"],
     'image'  => $row["image"]
    );
   }
   echo json_encode($output);
  }
 }
}
```

I am new to php and CodeIgniter and I am trying to do autocomplete with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to sort through the elements of the array using [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) (so case-insensitive) to look for your search string:

```
$users = [ 
           ['name'  => "John Doe", 'email'  => 'e@e.com'], 
           ['name'  => 'Patrice', 'email'  => 'pt@ex.com']
         ];
function fetch_data($data, $search) {
    return array_filter($data, function ($v) use ($search) { return stripos($v['name'], $search) !== false; });
}
print_r(fetch_data($users, 'e'));
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [name] => John Doe [email] => e@e.com )
    [1] => Array ( [name] => Patrice [email] => pt@ex.com ) 
)

print_r(fetch_data($users, 'p'));
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( [name] => Patrice [email] => pt@ex.com ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fjDg2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
$search_string = "e";
$keys = preg_grep("/$search_string/i", array_column($users, 'name'));

$result = [];
foreach($keys as $key => $value)
{
    $result[] = $users[$key];
}
//return $result to your autocomplete.
```

PHP Documentation on [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

I have tested the code.

[Test Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b335095a5ec4dd7752e8ea97cc18973bcb63a6ba)

Comment: This code doesn't actually work. Why is it the accepted answer?

Comment: @Nick I have updated my answer. I didn't check the code just now. `array_keys` should have worked for full match and not partial match.

Comment: Looks good now. I'm still amazed that someone would accept an answer that didn't even compile...

Comment: Oops was a mistake. I actually meant to accept tthe answer fom @Nick which worked for me. Can we change the accepted answer ?

Comment: @jungleMan you can change the accepted answer. Just tick the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

if want array like this

```
$users = [ 
            name: "John Doe", 
            name: 'Patrice',
         ];
```

then not need to extra loop, directly use like this :

```
$this->db->select("student_name as name,image");
$this->db->like('LOWER(student_name)',strtolower($query['name']));
$data = $this->db->get('tbl_student')->result_array();
$student_name=array();
if(count($data)>0)
{
    $student_name=array_column($data,'name');   
}

return $student_name;
```